# Performance of recursive Variadic function calls against simple if..else statements

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I hope the subject reflects what I want to ask here ... I gave my best.

We have to set certains variables based on several run-time conditions. We always went for if..else statements but I find them too cumbersome especially given there could be several conditions. I tried to develop something using c++11/17 features and came up with the following.

So my question is with respect to: Performance, and readability, would you prefer to use the following ?

```
template <typename DST, typename... Ts>
void SetValue(DST& dst, Ts&&... ts)
{
  CheckAndSetVal(dst, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

template <typename DST>
void CheckAndSetVal(DST&) {}

template <typename DST, typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<DST, T2> > CheckAndSetVal(DST& dst, T1&& cond, T2&& val, Ts&&... ts)
{
  if (cond())
    dst = val; // Assign the value here ...
  else
    CheckAndSetVal(dst, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

template <typename DST, typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<DST, T2> > CheckAndSetVal(DST& dst, T1&& cond, T2&& val, Ts&&... ts)
{
  if (cond())
    dst = val(); // Assign the value using this functor .. 
  else
    CheckAndSetVal(dst, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

  int i;
  //
  // In practive though the conditions are not as trivial as they look here. 
  //
  SetValue(i, []() { return false; }, 444
            , []() { return false; }, 999
            , []() { return true; }, []() { return 222; });
```

Comment: For readability, I would probably group `{cond, val}` in its own class, a "lazyOptional". with C++11, it means usage of `std::function` with something like `std::pair<std::function<bool(), std::function<T()>>` :-/ Using overloads for `lazyOptional(BFunc, TFunc)` and `lazyOptional(BFunc, T)`, from C++14, you might really use lambda type as return type and get rid of cost of `std::function`:-). .In C++17, you might alternatively have a optional factory.

Answer (score 3):

If readability of that function is a concern, you can always get rid of a lot of the SFINAE magic using C++17 :)

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<class DestT, class CondT, class ValueT, class... Ts>
void SetValue(DestT& out, CondT&& cond, ValueT&& value, Ts&&... ts)
{
    if (cond())
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<ValueT>)
        {
            out = value();
        }
        else
        {
            out = value;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) != 0)
        {
            SetValue(out, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    SetValue(i, []() { return false; }, 444,
                []() { return false; }, 999,
                []() { return true; }, []() { return 222; });

    return i;
}
```

Performance should be exactly the same for release builds and probably a bit slower on unoptimized builds. For example, the above code compiles down to `return 222` on gcc/clang with optimizations. Compile time may take a bit of a hit, though.

I'm not a fan of gigantic variadic function calls like this but sometimes they are worth it, when they save a lot of typing throughout a codebase. Without knowing your real usecase it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Firstly, I am surprised this compiles since the usage as a callable and as a value seem to be in the same function. Does this mean that only one of the if..else part is actually compiled in to object code ? If not, then how can, "out = value()" and "out = value" be in the same function ?

Comment: @lightsunray: with regular `if`, it would be problematic, but we use `if constexpr` here which "discards" the wrong branch.

Comment: @Asu: it makes it also clear that `out` might stay unmodified (so cannot return it in function as is).

Comment: @Asu: Thanks. The one with "if constexpr" is completely new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would prefer `if-else` statement or `?:` operators.
Easier to debug or to interpret crash dumps.
Easier to read by non-C++ developer or beginner developer.
And no solid disadvantages.

Comment: When it comes to readability, simple if..else cannot be beaten for a single variable. But in my usecase, I have several tens of such variables to be initialized at a single place. After I implemented this it does improve readability of the Code.